# jQuery from JavaScript console: download all files

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, automation

I am visiting a website hightail.com that someone sent me 200 of my wedding photos on. You can click each link to download the photo. Or you can sign up for $x per month and install software to download them all (avoiding this).

I can download the first photo using Chrome, jQuery and the JavaScript console with:

```
$('.downloadFile').click()
```

But I need to get all the photos, with this command:

```
$('.downloadFile').each(function(i, a){$(a).click()})
```

However this still only downloads the first file.

Please advise on how to correct this.

Comment: Even this only downloads the first file: `$('.downloadFile').each(function(i, a){$(a).delay(i*5000).trigger('click')})`

Comment: "Save Page As (complete)", and all the images should be in the folder tied to the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `trigger` cannot be used with `delay`, you must use JavaScript's `setTimeout`

`$('.downloadFile').each(function(i, a){
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(a).trigger('click')
  }, i*4000);
})`